# how i post json string when i post then show me message input data is require in logcat

Tags: android

API=

```
public static String getaddProject="http://10.10.10.64:10003/API/Project/Add";

 for(int i=0; i<iArr.size(); i++){

                    if(i==0){

                        st = "{\"userId\":" + iArr.get(i) + "}";
                        str += st;
                    }else if(i>0 && i<iArr.size()-1){
                        st = ",{\"userId\":" + iArr.get(i) + "}";
                        str+=st;
                    }else if(i==iArr.size()){
                        st = ",{\"userId\":" + iArr.get(i) + "}]}";
                        str+=st;
                    }
                }
                String myPost = "{\"project\":{\"Name\":"+ "\""+ title + "\""
                        + ",\"Description\":" + "\""+ desc + "\""
                        + ",\"createdBy\":" + usrid + ""
                        + ",\"startDate\":" + "\""+ startdate + "\""
                         + ",\"dueDate\":" + "\""+ duedate + "\""
                        + ",\"projectLeadId\":" + leadPosition + ""
                        + ",\"QAId\":" + QAssurencePosition + ""
                        + ",\"TotalHour\":" +"\""+ edtHour + "\""+ "},\"members\":[";
                myPost += str;
                myPost +="]}";
                RequestPackage myPackage = new RequestPackage();
                myPackage.setUri(getaddProject);
                myPackage.setMethod("POST");
                myPackage.setParam("My Post",myPost+"");
                new MyTask().execute(myPackage);
Toast.makeText(CreateProject.this,"Testing String: " + myPost,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                Log.d("My Post :",myPost);
            }
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it's virtually impossible to understand what the problem is.

Comment: when i post json string then show me in logcat {"data":null,"statusCode":200,"isSuccess":true,"message":"input data is required"}

Comment: We cannot know anything about this API of yours. Neither can we guess whether or not your JSON is valid (please check the resulting JSON string on a lint site). Are you sure you want to have a space character in your param name `My Post`?

Comment: this api use for add project and i have check it the json on JSON lint... my json is done ... but some problem coming on posting... i dont know why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MyTask class you have doInBackground method witch have to return your string answer and pass it to onPostExecute. Then in you will have :

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String answer) {
     Toast.makeText(CreateProject.this,"Testing String: " + answer,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
 }
```

Comment: Log.d("testing string:",result);
in log cat show result is : {"data":null,"statusCode":200,"isSuccess":true,"message":"input data is required"}

Comment: The placement of the Toast is ok. And has nothing to do with the problem. In onPostExecute one could Toast the received json text though.

Comment: i have received response . {"data":null,"statusCode":200,"isSuccess":true,"message":"input data is required"}